# Async Task Progress Dialog doesn't go away

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello 
I'm loading Tweets from a user account to show in a listview. Now I want to let the users know what's going on while they're waiting. I've implementend Async Task, but for some reason, onPostExcecute is never called. That's why the dialog is never removed.

Can someone give me a hint.. What am I doing wrong?

I can post my TweetAdapterClass if that's needed

This is my AsyncClass

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setTitle("Even geduld...");
        dialog.setMessage("De tweets worden ingeladen...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                adaptor = new TweetListAdaptor(MainActivity.this, R.layout.tweetitem, loadTweets());
                setListAdapter(adaptor);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        return null;

    }
}
```

LoadTweets looks like this:

```
private ArrayList<Tweets> loadTweets() {
    ArrayList<Tweets> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweets>();
    try {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=JobXXL_be&rpp=10");
        // HttpGet get = new
        // HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Stijn_messiaen&rp=10");

        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
        if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject session = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
                Tweets tweet = new Tweets();
                tweet.setTweet(session.getString("text"));
                tweet.setUser(session.getString("from_user"));
                // datum vertalen
                String date = session.getString("created_at").substring(5,
                        16);
                String[] arrDate = date.split(" ");
                int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(
                        arrDate[1].toString(), "string",
                        this.getPackageName());
                String maand = getResources().getString(id);
                date = arrDate[0].toString() + " " + maand + " "
                        + arrDate[2].toString();

                tweet.setDate(date);
                tweets.add(tweet);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TwitterFeedActivity", "Error loading JSON", e);
    }
    return tweets;
}
```

EDIT: I added my LoadTweets() in my `doInBackgroundMethod` and that solved my problems!

Comment: What does your loadTweets() method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the `ProgressDialog dialog` in the main class in which your AsyncTask class exists and only call the `dialog.show` and `dialog.dismiss` method in the AsyncTask class.

Comment: I did this, and initialize the dialog in `onCreate()`methode, but it didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use `onCreateDialog(int id)` in activity to create `ProgressDialog`. In AsyncTask call:

```
MainActivity.this.showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
```

To dismiss:

```
MainActivity.this.dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
```

Dialogs are connected with activity's context. When activity is recreated dialog should be recreated too but then instance of the dialog is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute() does not match the declaration Void. I am on the road so off the top of my head consider:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
```

More [here.](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/asynch)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, unfortunately. What's exactly wrong with the declaration. Except for `arg0` being changed in `args`, I don't see any difference.

Comment: @Hannelore I am on the road so I was not able to test my code. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and yeah this happened to me when onPostExecute didn't match the declaration... try something like `protected Void onPostExecute(Void... arg0)`

Next thing to do is to put Log.d("Your app", "Location of this code"); and check which part doesn't execute on Log file ...

Hope u will find the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, two things come to mind here..

1) Why is your onPostExecute not overridden like the onPreExecute and doInBackground?

2) Why is the doInBackground after the onPost Execute? Generally the order is

onPreExecute
doInBackground
onPostExecute

Comment: I know this comment is old, but just to let you know that, in Java, the `@Override` notation is optional.